# Return from Table 2 different Ids from same names on Table1

Tags: sql, oracle, inner-join, outer-join

I have been trying to develop a query to solve a problem but its been hard.

Table 1:

```
+------+----+
| NAME | ID |
+------+----+
| A    |  1 |
| A    |  2 |
| B    |  1 |
| B    |  5 |
| C    |  8 |
+------+----+
```

Table 2:

```
+------+----+
| NAME | ID |
+------+----+
| A    |  1 |
| A    |  4 |
| B    |  3 |
| B    |  5 |
| D    |  9 |
+------+----+
```

From these results, I need to return everything from table 2 that the name contains in table 1 and the ID don't.

So, this example, the return should be:

```
+------+----+
| NAME | ID |
+------+----+
| A    |  4 |
| B    |  3 |
+------+----+
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might wanna try this:

EDIT: replaced table1 and table2 with a simple subqueries in WITH clause.

```
WITH table1 AS
(
SELECT
  DECODE(LEVEL,1, 'A',2, 'A',3, 'B',4, 'B',5, 'C') AS name
  ,DECODE(LEVEL,1, 1,2, 2,3, 1,4, 5,5, 8) AS id
FROM
  dual
CONNECT BY LEVEL < 6
)
,table2 AS
(
SELECT
  DECODE(LEVEL,1, 'A',2, 'A',3, 'B',4, 'B',5, 'D') AS name
  ,DECODE(LEVEL,1, 1,2, 4,3, 3,4, 5,5, 9) AS id
FROM
  dual
CONNECT BY LEVEL < 6
)
SELECT
  t2.id
  ,t2.name
FROM
  table1 t1
  ,table2 t2
WHERE
  t1.name = t2.name -- here we take all the records from table2, which have the same names as in table1
MINUS -- then we "subtract" the records that have both the same name and id in both tables
SELECT
  t2.id
  ,t2.name
FROM
  table1 t1
  ,table2 t2
WHERE
  t1.name = t2.name
  AND t1.id = t2.id
```

Comment: No returns.. Will try to discover where is the problem

Comment: Hey. Updated my query with some examplary table1 and table2.

Comment: @AndrewMcCoist FWIW, your query worked fine for me, at least when I ran it against the same dataset that I used for my answer. I'm not entirely sure why the OP seems to be having issues with answers that appear to do what they've requested!

Answer (score 1):

I would do:

```
with t1 as (select 'A' name, 1 id from dual union all
            select 'A' name, 2 id from dual union all
            select 'B' name, 1 id from dual union all
            select 'B' name, 5 id from dual union all
            select 'C' name, 8 id from dual),
     t2 as (select 'A' name, 1 id from dual union all
            select 'A' name, 4 id from dual union all
            select 'B' name, 3 id from dual union all
            select 'B' name, 5 id from dual union all
            select 'D' name, 9 id from dual)
select name, id
from   t2
where  name in (select name from t1)
minus
select name, id
from   t1;

NAME         ID
---- ----------
A             4
B             3
```

Comment: Its returning the NAMES that t1 doesn't have.. And the query should show only IDs that T2 has and T1 don't with the same names. Like the example.

Comment: In what way is my query returning names that t1 doesn't have?! If that were the case, the results would include the (name, id) = ('D', 9), which they don't. My results of (name, id) = ('A', 4) and ('B', 3) match exactly with your desired outcome as per your question!

Comment: I prolly made a mistake converting to the right format. It just worked here.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a NOT EXISTS or similar:

```
SELECT  t2.*
FROM Table2 t2
WHERE NOT EXISTS
(
   SELECT 1
   FROM Tabl1 t1
   WHERE t1.Name = t2.Name
   AND t1.Id = t2.Id
);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT T1.ID,T1.NAME
FROM TABLE2 T1 INNER JOIN TABLE1 T2 ON T1.NAME = T2.NAME
               LEFT JOIN TABLE1 T3 ON T3.ID = T1.ID
WHERE T3.ID IS NULL
```